# There's a yellow duck on the bottom right of my IPS SE site, asking me to "speak up a little"

Tags: discussion, support

On the IPS main site, I just encountered a yellow duck on the bottom right, and it's asking me to "speak up a little".  It even made a "quack" noise.

What's going on?  I haven't slept all night, and it's about 7am here in New York.

Am I hallucinating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not hallucinating. :P

This is an April Fool pun by SE team. AFAIK, they do that every year. There is nothing to worry about. You just have to talk to that duck just like user who asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83451/65039).

According to the [Taken from Rubber Duck popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdkhi.png),

> Whenever you’re stuck, [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is a powerful method for solving even the most difficult problems. Insights are often found by simply describing the problem aloud.

Related: [Main Meta Discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/321725)

Comment: And, BTW, talk to the duck and listen/read until the end :)